# Flickr integration in iphone app not working

Tags: iphone, ios, flickr

I am trying to integrate flickr in my app. Therefore, to begin with, I used the project

https://codeload.github.com/josephstein/Flickr-OAuth-iOS/zip/master

Although, I am able to login to flickr but the part where the application needs authorization (pressing the "OK I'll Authorize" button where the app asks permission to access user profile), it shows the error-

"oauth_problem=verifier_invalid"

I tried to find the solution but couldn't find anything helpful.

Thanks.!

Comment: i am getting temporary token but then application is crashed.